# Why the 2 norm of symmetric matrix A in bounded by its infinity norm?

Tags: matrix-norms

For an abstract matrix $A$ of dimension $p\times p$ and $p$ can approach infinity, we known that $\|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt{p}\|A\|_\infty$. However, in some papers, e.g., [the sentences below A.18 in page 13](https://dachxiu.chicagobooth.edu/download/GICS.pdf), and [the sentences above Lemma 3 in page 13](https://dachxiu.chicagobooth.edu/download/PCA_COV.pdf), I see that when $A$ is symmetric, $\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_\infty$, how to prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of the norms $\Vert A \Vert_2, \Vert A \Vert_\infty$? Are those the Schatten-norms? Or the operator norm from $\mathbb{R}^p$ with the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ norms?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\lambda_\max(A'A)}$ and $\|A\|_\infty=\max_{1\leq i\leq p}\sum_{j=1}^p|a_{ij}|$

Comment: Hmmm, ok. So for a a symmetric matrix, the first norm is just the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues. Now I don't see how to relate this to the second norm :(

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have listed two papers where the result was used.